# Concatenate certain elements from a cell array into a numeric array - MATLAB

Tags: matlab, cell-array

I have a nested cell array `A`, for example `A` is `1 x 6` cell.

Each cell of `A` contains another array of cells (for ex. `A{1} = 1 x n` cell).

Each cell of `A{1}{1}` contains other cell arrays  `A{1}{1} = 1 x n` cell

I would like to list the content of the cell in a unique array.

```
A = cell(1,2);
A{1} = cell(1,2);
A{2} = cell(1,1);
A{1}{1} = [{1} {2}];
A{1}{2} = [{3} {4}];
A{2}{1} = [{5} {6}];

vec = [];
for i = 1 : size(A,2)

 for j = 1 : size(A{1,i},2)
    vec = [vec; cell2mat(A{1,i}{1,j}(:,2))];
 end

end

vec = [2;4;6]
```

Is there a way to avoid the for loop?

Thanks

Comment: That's a complete change-over by the way! :)

Comment: yes I know....sorry.. should I post another question?

Comment: Nah it's fine I guess. At least assume random values and show us as sample, A{1} maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See is this works for you -

```
A_horzcat = horzcat(A{:})
out = cell2mat(vertcat(A_horzcat{:}))
vec = out(:,2)
```

---

Another approach (a one-liner! and I like it better) -

```
vec = arrayfun(@(x) x{1}{2}, [A{:}]).'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot...but I did a mistake in my test case.. :( now it is complete...it's a bit different...I know

Comment: perfectly...10 time faster than the for loop in my case

Comment: @gabboshow Wow, well if you pre-allocate for your loopy code? Of course you don't the length of `vec`, so that's the catch there. Anyways this works, so all's good!!

Comment: for loop 12.2 sec (allocated)
your solution 2.9 sec

Comment: @gabboshow Wooo! One more loopy code down! ;) Well arrayfun uses loops inside it too, but guess it performs well here :)

Comment: @gabboshow By the way, the tests you just performed, are those against the first approach or the second one?